# Batch file name in .bat file listing the whole file path

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename

I saw multiple posts on the topic I am asking a question, and tried to apply different solutions, but cannot make it work. I have a set of files `xx_date.ext1` that I need to change to `xx_date_suf.ext2` in bulk. But I do need to list the full directory path where files are located. Trying to do it dos .bat file. 
I tried to apply this solution with some minor changes that I found in one of the posts:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for %%i in (<Directory name here>\*) do (
  set filename=%%~ni
  ren "%%~i" "!filename:~0,5!%%~xi"
)

endlocal
```

No avail. I know that the above solution changing 5 char in a file name, but I do not need to count the number of characters.Just simple rename I described above.

Comment: Your code and your explanation aren't the same.  Is `xx_date` exactly 7 characters or are the filenames some other format?

Comment: I provided the example I tried to use, but in reality I do not want to deal with character length. Just rename the extension and add the suffix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for the verbal explanation that you provided:

```
@echo off
cd /d "c:\folder"
for %%a in (*.ext1) do ren "%%a" "%%~na_suf.ext2"
```

Or this:

```
@echo off
for %%a in ("c:\folder\*.ext1") do ren "%%a" "%%~na_suf.ext2"
```

Comment: Why can't I just use the full path instead of issuing cd command first